# Option Value on datalist

Tags: php, html

Can anybody explain to me why I am not having same results with this? Both works but the first just give me the first word of the sql varchar and bellow it the full and the second gives me everything with nothing below. Anyone knows why?

Method 1->

```
<datalist id="access">    <?php
           $dbcon= new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
           $sql = "SELECT a_name FROM travellers_access";
           $methodsAvailable = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
           $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($methodsAvailable);            
             if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($methodsAvailable)) {
                  echo "<option value=".$row['a_name'].">" . $row['a_name'] . "</option>";
             } } ?>
 </datalist>     
 <input class="custom" type="text" name="f_method" list="access" required>
```

Method 2 ->

```
    <datalist id="access"><?php
    $dbcon = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);            
    $sql = "select a_name from travellers_access";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) ;   ?>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['a_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['a_name']; ?></option>
    <?php } mysqli_close($db_connection);?>
    </datalist>
            <input class="custom" type="text" id="pcategory" autocomplete="off" list="access">
```